# Codeacademy's rock, paper, scissors game

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, conditional-statements

I am trying to figure out how to center (both vertically and horizontally) my `innerHTML` keeping in mind the length of th content. Here are my HTML and CSS.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <p id="demo"></p>
            <script>
                var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
                var computerChoice = Math.random();
                if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
                    computerChoice = "rock";
                } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
                    computerChoice = "paper";
                } else {
                    computerChoice = "scissors";
                } document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Computer: " + computerChoice;

                var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
                    if(choice1 === choice2) {
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The result is a tie!";
                    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
                        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Congratulatioins, you win!";
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById("dmeo").innerHTML = "Sorry, the computer shows paper. You lost!";
                        }
                    } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
                        if (choice2 === "rock") {
                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Congratulatioins, you win!";
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Sorry, the computer shows scissors. You lost!";
                        }
                    } else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
                        if (choice2 === "paper") {
                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Congratulatioins, you win!";
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Sorry, the computer shows rock. You lost!";
                        }
                    }
                }

                compare (userChoice, computerChoice);
            </script>

.container {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

body {
    background-image: url(images/bg-img.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin: 0;
}

#demo {

    font-family: Impact;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #cddc39;
    text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(106, 209, 25, 0.62);
}
```

Comment: Is site is pretty useful for centering things in css: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with multiple methods.

Option 1: 
You can center the div with the use of negative margins:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    margin-right: -25%;
}
```

Option 2: You can use the less supported css transform: translate

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 50%;

    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

I suggest option 1 because it is supported alot better. But hey, Whatever floats your boat ;)

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped me a lot. However, is there a way to make all the text centered. What I mean is that when the script shows "The result is a tie!" or "Congratulations!" it goes a bit to the left.

Comment: You can always try adding text-align: center;

Comment: Wow... Sorry for the stupid questions. And thanks again for the help. Positioning really bugs me. :(

Comment: You're very welcome! Would you be so kind to mark your question as answered so it can be closed? - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: center;` within the container selector should do the trick.

You can also use 'flexbox' to center both horizontally and vertically:

```
.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[Useful guide for flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)